# Media library only show 2 items per page?

Tags: pagination, attachments, media, media-library

For some reason WordPress media manager is only showing 2 images per page? This is happening on 2 separate sites now and I can't get rid of it.

Is there a way to manipulate items per page for the wp-admin media library?

Comment: This looks like a plugin is hooking into the wrong place. Can you disable all plugins and revert back to the Twenty Ten theme to see whether this solves the problem? Then re-enable the plugins one by one to find out which one is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Jan - it was the 'more fields' plugin and the temp plugin fix is here;

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-more-fields-media-library-only-shows-5-images-at-a-time-and-not-10?replies=10